# Jquery upgrade - 1.8 to 2.1.4, $(window) click vs $(document) click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I recently updated my project with latest jquery version.

For jquery 1.8, following statement worked:

```
$(window).on('click', 'button[data-mynav]', function() {
 console.log('hit');
}
);
```

But it stopped working with jquery 2.1.4, but if i use $(document) instead of $(window) it works, that is:

```
$(document).on('click', 'button[data-mynav]', function() {
 console.log('hit');
}
);
```

Can anyone please explain, why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It stop working already on 1.8.1

```html
<button a>works</button>
<button b>fails</button>

<!-- working -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

  $(window).on('click', 'button[a]', function() {
    this.innerHTML = 'hit';
  });
  
  jQuery.noConflict(true);
  
</script>

<!-- not working -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

  $(window).on('click', 'button[b]', function() {
    this.innerHTML = 'hit';
  });
  
</script>
```

This is there [changelog](https://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/30/jquery-1-8-1-released/) between 1.8.0 and 1.8.1

My guess is on bug #12383 git: [afd717d](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/afd717d)

I don't know exactly why it stop working as they didn't mention any breaking changes

Answer (score 0):

some time its better to move forward without caring anything,
this is the time you better start using

```
$(document).on('click', '#selector', function() {

}
);
```

coz jquery is currently using and continue to use it.

Comment: "Don't do what you're asking to do" is an acceptable answer if you provide substantive feedback on WHY you're telling the OP "Don't do that." Give a bit more background about why you're directing the OP away from their desired solution path.